# Uninstall X Server Entirely

Tags: server, apt, nginx

I (rather stupidly) installed `Ubuntu-Desktop` on my server installation simply so I could remote in and then run a graphical tool to join a windows domain. I realised this was stupid and went about it using `sssd` and the `cli`. I've uninstalled this using `apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop` however, I'm left with a whole bunch of random `X` crap.

I've tried using `apt-get purge libx11.* libqt.*` however, this throws the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 colord : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (>= 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-core (< 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.10.1-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: That does nothing useful here.